# Online collaboration on TFS

Tags: azure, tfs

is it possible to collaborate online with TFS? I mean, when I move a task, others can see it in real time without sharing screen or updating the page. Thank you!

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1 RC1 and higher has live updates on work items. If you change a work item someone else has open in view mode, it will update in their client.

Alternatively

- You can enable notifications using `../DefaultCollection/_usersSettings/notifications`
- You can use the `Follow` icon to follow a work item. Any changes will result in an e-mail to you saying the item has changed, and what has changed.
  [image]
- If you move a story out of an iteration, the Taskboard (`../_sprints/taskboard/..`) view updates automatically for all users viewing that iteration
- Similarly, if you add/edit/move/change state on a task in an iteration the Taskboard will update.